# Define the order of vertical stacking of columns

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want the `div` containing 1 to be on right on desktop but on top on mobile. Is there way to achieve that with `bootstrap`, preferably without using custom CSS?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                1
            </div>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways that you can reorder the columns. I recommend you to use bootstrap 4 classes rather than custom CSS since you already use bootstrap.

---

- In the HTML code, **first** write the columns that you want to position at the top on mobile. And use the **`order-sm-1`** class. But i think it is better to use **`order-sm-last`** since it is more intuitive. In this particular case, they both function the same.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 order-sm-last bg-primary">
        First on mobile
      </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 bg-danger">
        2 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

2. Maintain the order of columns as you have written and use **`order-last`** and **`order-sm-first`** for the first column.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 order-last order-sm-first">
                2
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                First on mobile
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Alternatively, you can use **`order-1`** and **`order-sm-0`**

Answer (score 4):

You should use `bootstrap order classes` for maintaining order of your elements. Here is the live demo to your question -

[Reordering Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#reordering)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 order-md-2">
            <div class="card card-body bg-info">1st on mobile</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card card-body">2nd</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```